# How to implement multiple authentication methods in Spring WebFlux Security?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I'd like to provide two ways to authenticate in my application, one is basic auth (users), and the other is some kind of token based (technical users). I understand that I need a custom `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` but I can't find clues on the big picture. (Actually, there are a very few insights for MVC, and none for WebFlux.)

1) How do I populate the Authentication's name and credentials in the token based approach? If I configure Spring Security to use httpBasic it's already populated. Some kind of filter needed?

2) How do I distinguish in the authentication manager where the credentials are coming from? Do I have to lookup in the userRepository and (if not found) in the technicalUserRepository too?

3) Do I have to override the `SecurityContextRepository`? All the tutorials do it but I don't see any reason to do so. What is it exactly? [This](https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-security-webflux-jwt) source states that "**SecurityContextRepository** is similar to **userDetailsService** provided in regular spring security that compares the username and password of the user." but I think he means `ReactiveUserDetailsService` (neither `UserDetailsService` nor `ReactiveUserDetailsService` does that by the way, it's just for user lookup).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since i am decent at Webflux and i have worked a lot with oauth2 i'll try and answer some of your questions.

**1) How do I populate the Authentication's name and credentials in the
token based approach? If I configure Spring Security to use httpBasic
it's already populated. Some kind of filter needed?**

A token never contains credentials. A token is something you get issued after an authentication has been done. So usually you authenticate against an issuing service. After you have authenticated yourself against that service you will be issued a token.

If its an oauth2 token the token itself is just a random string. It contains no data about the user itself. When this token is sent (using the appropriate header) to a service using spring security. Spring security has a token filter that will basically check that the token is valid, usually by sending the token to the issuer and asking "is this token valid?".

If using a jwt, its different, the jwt must contain some information like issuer, scopes, subject etc. etc. but its basically the same thing, there is a built in filter that will validate the jwt by sending it to the issuer (or using a jwk that the service fetches from the issuer so it can verify the integrity of the jwt without doing an extra request).

**2) How do I distinguish in the authentication manager where the credentials are coming from? Do I have to lookup in the userRepository and (if not found) in the technicalUserRepository too?**

You don't You usually define multiple SecurityWebFilterChains for different url paths. I have not done this in Webflux Spring Security, but thats how you do it in regular Spring Applications, and i don't see any difference here. Unless you are doing something crazy custom.

**3) Do I have to override the SecurityContextRepository? All the tutorials do it but I don't see any reason to do so. What is it exactly? This source states that "SecurityContextRepository is similar to userDetailsService provided in regular spring security that compares the username and password of the user." but I think he means ReactiveUserDetailsService (neither UserDetailsService nor ReactiveUserDetailsService does that by the way, it's just for user lookup).**

The answer here is *probably no*. You see Spring security 4 had very bad support for oauth2 and especially JWT. So people got accustomed to writing their own JWT parsers. When spring Security 5 came, Spring implemented a jwt filter that you can configure and use built in. But there are a lot of outdated Spring Security tutorials out there and foremost there are a lot of developers that don't read the official documentation.

They mostly google tutorials and get the wrong information and then work on that.

But easy explained:

**SecurityContextRepository**
If you have session based authentication (server establishes a session with a client) it will store the SecurityContext (session) in ThreadLocal during a request. But as soon as the request ends, the session will go lost unless we store it somewhere. The `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` will use the `SecurityContextRepository` to extract the session from ThreadLocal and store it, most common is to store it in the HttpSession.

**AuthenticationManager**
Override this if you want to do a custom authentication process. Example if you want to validate something, call a custom LDAP, database, etc etc. It\s here you perform you authentication. But remember, most standard logins (like ldap, sql-servers, basic login etc.) already have prebuilt configurable managers implemented, when you select what login type like `.httpBasic()` you will get a pre-implemented AuthenticationManager.

**UserDetailsManager**
You override this when you want create a custom UserDetails object (also usually called Principal) In the UserDetailsManager you do you database lookup and fetch the user and then build and return a UserDetails object.

Those two interfaces are the most regular custom implementations, and are used if you need to to basic authentication/session based authentication.

If you wish to do token, you have to think about, who is the token issuer? usually the issuer is separate and all services just get tokens and validate them against the issuer.

I hope this explains some of the questions. I have written this on the bus so some things are probably wrong and not 100% correct etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insights! One thing left unanswered only, maybe my question was inaccurate. Lets say that the users are authenticated via basic auth header, while the technical users send their login information in post body. When I override the ReactiveAuthenticationManager I'm receiveing an already populated Authentication object (created by a basic auth filter?). How do I do the same for the post body in the second case?

Comment: when you authenticate through basic you are performing what is called a "session" login. So your session will get stored in the HttpSession, and that will send back a cookie to the client after correct authentication.

Comment: If you wish to write your own login (which i dont recommend, you should in general never roll your own authentication if you dont know what you are doing and have login experience) you need to perform the authentication yourself and then create the cookie yourself and return to the client etc. etc.

Then you probably need to map this to a different url, and this will get messy fast. I do not recommend handling multiple authentications and verifications in the same application.